# Swagger DefaultGenerator class not found?

Tags: java, swagger

I am using swagger-codegen-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar

When i try to create an instance of the Codegenerator:

```
import io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator;
...

DefaultGenerator gen = new DefaultGenerator();
```

i get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$TemplateLoader
at Swapper.swapApi(Swapper.java:46)
at SwapperTest.testSwapApi(SwapperTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$TemplateLoader
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
```

I have no idea whats going wrong. Anybody does?

Comment: It seems you're missing a dependency com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$TemplateLoader. Check your classpath

Comment: Hi you are right, i thought swagger had the jmustache dependency already included... but i inlcuded it now manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're missing a dependency com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$TemplateLoader.

In fact if you look to the [pom.xml](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/pom.xml) of swagger-codegen-plugin you will find there is a dependency to `<jmustache-version>1.9</jmustache-version>`

Be sure this dependency is available in your classpath.

Comment: Thx for hint with pom.xml. I dont use maven usually, so i often ignore the pom.xml files